# iTextSharp - How to read all comments and reply from PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Using below code i am able to read only one Comment per page, How to read all the comments from all the pages from PDF. Or any way to get all the comments List from PDF in one shot.

```
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfRead.NumberOfPages; ++page)
{
PdfDictionary pagedic = pdfRead.GetPageN(page);
PdfArray annotarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pagedic.Get(PdfName.ANNOTS));

if (annotarray == null || annotarray.Size == 0)
    continue;
string all_string = "";
foreach (PdfObject A in annotarray.ArrayList)
{
    PdfDictionary AnnotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A);

    if (AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.TEXT))
    {
        all_string += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T).ToString() +"\n";
        all_string += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS).ToString()+ "\n";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this issue. I have checked this code that does not get any comment on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Pages are organized in a page tree. Each leaf of the page tree refers to a page dictionary. The `/Annots` entry is one of the optional keys of a page dictionary. It contains an array of annotations that belong to a specific page.

You are looping over every page dictionary of every page in the page tree, retrieving the `/Annots` array of every page dictionary. This is the correct procedure.

Your question *"How to read all the comments from all the pages from PDF?"* is wrong. You are already reading all the comments from all the pages from a PDF the correct way. It is inherent to PDF that the annotations are organized in this way. Even if there was an iTextSharp method to give you all the annotations in one single method, *it would use the exact same code you are using now.* What would that gain you? It would take the same amount of processing time.